# Viscosity from terminal settling velocity of a sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag, viscosity

> [image: Blockquote]

I don't have an attempted answer to this question because I don't really know where to start. The *Tip* says to start from a force balance for the sphere, but I'm not sure on how to do that.

I know that the motion of the sphere is governed by Newton's law of acceleration

$m \frac{dV}{dt} = F_g - F_b - F_D$

but is this the force balance? And how will a force balance help me find a relation to express the ratio $\frac{μ_1}{μ_2}$

I apologize if this is considered to be a homework question but I appreciated all help on how to answer this problem.
Thank you!

**Edit: Attempted solution**

Gravitational force:
$\ce{F_g=\frac{4}{3} π R^3 g ρ_p}$

Bouyancy force:
$\ce{F_b=\frac{4}{3} π R^3 g ρ_f}$

Solving $F_D =F_g - F_b$ for $\ce{fluid 1}$ and $\ce{fluid 2}$, and rearranging them to solve for the viscosity:

**fluid 1:** $\ce{μ_1 = \frac{4R^3g(ρ_p -ρ_1)}{9d_pv}}$

**fluid 2:** $\ce{μ_2 = \frac{4R^3g(ρ_p -ρ_2)}{9d_pv}}$

Finding the relation $\frac{μ_1}{μ_2}$ gives:

$\frac{μ_1}{μ_2}$ = $\frac{(ρ_p -ρ_1)}{(ρ_p -ρ_2)}$

and that would be my answer

Comment: The gist is to assume that the sphere is held just below the surface with zero velocity. When the sphere is released it will accelerate to some terminal velocity. (The compressibility of the fluid is ignored.) So you're trying to solve for the velocity at infinite time. Thus $F_D = F_g - F_b$

Comment: In other words while the sphere is accelerating downwards $$F_D < F_g - F_b$$

Comment: Start with defining the two other forces, which also have densities in them.

Comment: @MaxW I have added an attempted solution if You could please check if it is correct I would be very grateful

Comment: It is fully correct

Comment: @HarshWasnik Thank you!